# Python: with open does not read anything the second time

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, popen

I want to log the return of the `pip show` command, and identify the version of a package (`pytest` for example). If another log is present, it shall be overwritten.

So I decided to write the `pip show` command in a file and then reopen it in read mode to parse it. The second `open` does not read anything if I am not placing a breakpoint on the `for` loop line.

I use two different file names, even do a `seek(0)` before actually reading...

```
# checking the installed package version using pip. Writing to file for further use
with open("lib_install.log", "w") as pip_log:
    subprocess.Popen(["pip", "show", "pytest"], stdout=pip_log, stderr=pip_log)

# Lets retrieve the log and parse for the version
current_version = "not installed properly"
with open("lib_install.log", "r") as pip_log_read:
    pip_log_read.seek(0)
    for line in pip_log_read.readlines():
        if "Version: " in line:
            current_version = line.strip("Version: ")
            break
```

Do you guys have any idea?

By the way, if you know how I can use `pip` without `Popen`, I am all ears.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using `Popen`, your main thread is going to continue to execute so it is non-deterministic and might execute before the pip command is finished.

```
with open("lib_install.log", "w") as pip_log:
    subprocess.Popen(["pip", "show", "pytest"], stdout=pip_log, stderr=pip_log)

current_version = "not installed properly" # This will not necessarily be
                                           # executed after the Popen is done.
```

Use `subprocess.call` or use the [`wait`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait) method of the Popen returned object.

```
with open("lib_install.log", "w") as pip_log:
    p = subprocess.Popen(["pip", "show", "pytest"], stdout=pip_log, stderr=pip_log)
    p.wait()
```

Comment: You are right. It is working now, using p.wait(). Thank you. I thought that the "with open" structure assured you that the file was closed when leaving it...

Comment: @joris255: note: `Popen()`+`wait()` is just `subprocess.call()`. Use `subprocess.check_call()` to raise an exception automatically if `pip` fails

Comment: your comment is incorrect `current_version` is run strictly after `Popen()`. `Popen()` starts the child process and returns without waiting for the child process to finish but there are no other threads.

Comment: It was more along the lines of "pip_log might not have been written to in the subprocess when you try to read it in the main thread"